# Can I arrange the categories in Unity's dash?

Tags: unity, 11.04, lenses, unity-dash

I would like to know if dash supports rearranging the categories that appear when one starts writing something.

To be more precise, I would like whatever appears from the ask ubuntu lens to be below the actual applications (for example if I write gedit, the application should be on top and the questions about it below)

The way it is now creates a rather "important" problem : since some time is needed to search askubuntu and return the answer, dash keeps changing sizes every time I press a new letter - making it impossible for me to hit the one I want.

EDIT : In case anyone hasn't noticed, the latest update has fixed the problem, putting applications on top of custom lenses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not right now, there is no way to manually rearrange elements ATM. May be something will be added in 11.10

There is also a bug report filed about this behavior:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/737379